# Proper way to treat NodeList as array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

Ok, so I know that the conventional wisdom of the "proper" way to use the results of a document.querySelectorAll (a NodeList) is to convert it to an array by using something like:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(elements)
```

However, I have been experimenting with using them directly as array-like objects and it seems to work in structures such as:

```
document.querySelectorAll('selector').forEach(elem => console.log(elem.tagName));
```

My question is, are there unexpected consequences of using this much more convenient syntax?

Comment: It's fine if your browser supports it; not all do.

Comment: [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) of `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` You can add the [short polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) for IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although `NodeList` is not an `Array`, it is possible to iterate over it with `forEach()`. It can also be converted to a real `Array` using `Array.from()`.
>
> However, some older browsers have not implemented `NodeList.forEach()` nor `Array.from()`. This can be circumvented by using `Array.prototype.forEach()` — see this document's Example.

--- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

All browsers except **IE** support all additional methods. Thus it is somewhat safe to use.

NodeList implements:

- [PROPERTY] length - Same as `array.length`
- [METHOD] item - `list.item(5) === list[5]`
- [METHOD] forEach - Same as `array.forEach`
- [METHOD] entries - Same as `array.entries`
- [METHOD] values - Same as `array.values`
- [METHOD] keys - Same as `array.keys`

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec, `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which is *only* guarunteed to have it's elements and a `length` property. So even if your browser does support this, it's a bad idea. If you're looking for a more convenient syntax, you can use `Array.from` or the spread operator:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('selector')).forEach()
[...document.querySelectorAll('selector')].forEach()
```